# ERROR: [Characteristic] 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 2): Error: Could not read characteristic handle 2: Unreachable Arduino Nano BLE

Tags: python, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, imu

I need to measure the accelerations of a moving object. For this, I am using the Arduino Nano 33 BLE, which has the integrated sensor IMU LSM9DS1, so I am trying to read and save the accelerations from the sensor and be able to keep them in the computer, all through communication BLE, the problem is that I get an error:
raise BleakError(f"Characteristic {char_specifier} not found!") bleak.exc.BleakError: Characteristic 00002011-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb not found!
Try using the service_explorer.py example with this device, the result shows this error:

```
2023-07-31 09:28:30,443 __main__ INFO: starting scan...
2023-07-31 09:28:30,751 __main__ INFO: connecting to device...
2023-07-31 09:28:31,229 __main__ INFO: connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,229 __main__ INFO: [Service] 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 1): Generic Access Profile
2023-07-31 09:28:31,245 __main__ ERROR:   [Characteristic] 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 2): Device Name (read), Error: Could not read characteristic handle 2: Unreachable
2023-07-31 09:28:31,246 __main__ ERROR:   [Characteristic] 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 4): Appearance (read), Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,247 __main__ INFO: [Service] 00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 6): Generic Attribute Profile
2023-07-31 09:28:31,247 __main__ INFO:   [Characteristic] 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 7): Service Changed (indicate)
2023-07-31 09:28:31,248 __main__ ERROR:     [Descriptor] 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 9): Client Characteristic Configuration, Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,248 __main__ INFO: [Service] 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 10): Serial Port
2023-07-31 09:28:31,249 __main__ ERROR:   [Characteristic] 00002101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 11): Vendor specific (read,notify), Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,250 __main__ ERROR:     [Descriptor] 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 13): Client Characteristic Configuration, Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,251 __main__ ERROR:   [Characteristic] 00002102-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 14): Vendor specific (read,notify), Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,251 __main__ ERROR:     [Descriptor] 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 16): Client Characteristic Configuration, Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,252 __main__ ERROR:   [Characteristic] 00002103-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 17): Vendor specific (read,notify), Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,252 __main__ ERROR:     [Descriptor] 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb (Handle: 19): Client Characteristic Configuration, Error: Not connected
2023-07-31 09:28:31,253 __main__ INFO: disconnecting...
2023-07-31 09:28:31,261 __main__ INFO: disconnected
```

I tried changing the UUID in the python code, I also tried using 128-bit UUIDs instead of 16-bit UUIDs, and now the error is something else:

await winrt_char.write_client_characteristic_configuration_descriptor_async(OSError: [WinError -2147467260] Operation aborted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.